# Argument of\emph has an extra}

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, biblatex, fonts, graphics

Can someone help me to resolve this error: Argument of\emph has an extra}.[image]

The line mentioned 694:
\textbf{\emph{NOTE: }ISO recommends that capitalization follow the accepted practice for the language or script in which the information is given}.\ See \cite{b20}.

EDIT:

The error occurs when compiling the IEEE Access LaTex Template in Overleaf.

The line as already mentioned is at 684 where `\emph` follows a `\textbf`.

EDIT 2:

The source of the problem is found in `ieeeaccess.cls` of the referenced template at line 56-58:

```
\def\textit#1{{\it #1}}%
\let\emph\textit
\def\textbf#1{{\bf #1}}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a compilable code reproducing the problem.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of error messages. Screenshots can be hard to read (this one is hard to read for me), they cannot be searched that easily by search engines and they pose an accessibility issue for people with screen readers. Note that we will only be able to help you properly if you not only show us the error message you get, but also a short example document (reduced to the bare minimum) that reproduces the message, a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: you have a missing `}` somewhere but as you have not shown any code, impossible to say where.

Comment: Any news here? In its current form the question can not be answered properly. Please show us a short example document that reproduces the error. If there is no development here in due time, I will vote to close the question as 'needs more details'.

Comment: MWE in this case is a template example that you can download at [here](https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/guide-for-authors/submission-guidelines/) (check for a link of the LaTeX template). By the way, I got the the same problem. I solved it by removing any "problem" paragraphs causing the error messages.

Comment: For the future readers: this question is valid. Just download IEEE access template and compile it. The error will appear as questioned. The solution is to remove \textbf before \emph and the corresponding curly brackets. I don't know why \textbf cannot be nested with \emph in this template.

Comment: The error does not appear if you use an updated IEEE Access template from the IEEE Template Selector service. It has an \emph removed on line 695. Though that version has another issue with an extra beginning blank page due to an unwanted period on line 34, simply deleted the period.